# Is Git and TFVC repo types in a team project just for the team project?

Tags: git, azure-devops, tfvc

I've been using TFVC for a while now. But now, due to needing to be remote sometimes, I'm thinking of using Git in VSTS more often on some of my projects. I came across this post [Change Visual Studio Online team project source control from TFVC to Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30640907/change-visual-studio-online-team-project-source-control-from-tfvc-to-git) which is excellent, but I've got a question for clarification. The last answer (as I post this question) by Krzysztof Branicki was very helpful to me. I now know that if a team project in TFS 2015 Update 1 (and higher) and VSTS is created with a repo type of TFVC, you can add Git to the team project. And the same is true if the team project was created to use Git, it can have TFVC added to it. But the distinction here is to the team project. I am interpreting to mean that it does not apply to any projects within the team project. So, as in my case, since most of my team projects in VSTS I created I used TFVC as the repo type, even if I were to add Git to a team project, that won't be applied to any project within that team project. I'm interpreting it to mean that whatever repo type a project was created under, it will only have that repo type applied to it. Am I interpreting that correctly?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "project" within a team project. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Sure. What I mean is I can create a ASP.NET MVC project, within the TFS/VSTS team project. Then later I can create a UWP project, also within the same team project, etc. This can be done days later. And they're not a part of the same solution. Perhaps I should I used the term Visual Studio solution, instead of projects.

Comment: Source code isn't part of a "team project" in any sense other than it's stored in a source control repository, which is part of a team project. If you're asking, "If I add a Git repo, is my source code moved from a TFVC repo to a Git repo?", then the answer is no.

Comment: That's what I thought Daniel, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source code isn't part of a "team project" in any sense other than it's stored in a source control repository, which is part of a team project.

If you're asking, "If I add a Git repo, is my source code moved from a TFVC repo to a Git repo?", then the answer is no.

If you're making the switch from TFVC to Git, it's important to understand the differences between them and how to properly structure a Git repo and implement a proper branching strategy. Distributed VCS is very different from centralized VCS, and different patterns and practices apply.

Comment: I was asking about this because I want to take a ASP.NET project, which I created as a TFVC repo years ago. Looks like I'll have to just copy the code to a new location and create a Git repo there using VSTS. Oh well. Thank you, Daniel.

Comment: Git-TFS is an open source tool that can convert a TFVC repository into a Git repository. You can also choose "Import" from the repository menu and VSTS can convert the repo for you, with some limitations.